# Reading 12 Bit input c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a small program that can read and write 12 bit. The Input shouldn't have any issues but I'll include it so you understand the problem better. The input should be created as sample.lzw by the OFStream12Bits.cpp/main.cpp included below and the output should be reading the sample.lzw back from the write functions. I'm having problems with the output and getting code mismatch in the main when reading the code. I think the issues is from the operator>> and the readBit functions not sure exactly though. 
Thank you very much for any help, I've been stuck on this for awhile!

The instructions for the readbit are as follows...

```
//basic readBit
//read12Bits(): 12Bit =
//declare Result : 12Bit = 0;
//for i = 1 to 12
//do
//declare lBit : Bit = get bit from input
//if(lBit == 1)
//then Result = (1 << (i-1)) + Result; //set bit at index i
//od
//return result
```

The part I don't understand is I need to return *this but there is no + operator so I can't use result to set the bit at index i. at the moment I have the code like this.

```
IFStream12Bits& IFStream12Bits::operator>>(int& a12BitValue)
{
    //int Result = a12BitValue;
    //a12BitValue = ((a12BitValue & 0x0fff) << 1);
    a12BitValue = a12BitValue & 0x0fff;


    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        int bit = readBit();
        if (bit == 1)
        {
            a12BitValue = (1 << (i - 1)) + a12BitValue; //set bit at index i
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Also The instructions for the readBit are as follows...

```
//implements mapping process. returns 0 or 1 depending on value of fBuffer[fByteIndex] & (1 << (fBitIndex - 1))
//see how it works with experiments
//at start check if (fByteCount == 0){reload();} then use reload() called as buffer does not contain any data before calling reload
//next fetch the bit store and then advance fByteIndex and fBitIndex 
//if fBitIndex(highest to lowest) reaches 0 you need to switch to the next byte in the buffer. and also decrment fByteCount
//then finally return result
```

And the code is

```
int IFStream12Bits::readBit()
{
    if (fByteCount == 0){ reload(); }

    //int bit = fBuffer[fByteIndex] & (1 << (fBitIndex - 1));

    int bit = fBuffer[fByteIndex] & (1 << (fBitIndex - 1));
    int result = 0;

    cout << "bit: " << bit << endl;

    //added this just cause
    if (bit == 0)
    {
        result = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        result = 1;
    }

    //additional logic required?
    fByteIndex++;
    fBitIndex--;


    //switch to next byte in the buffer
    if (fBitIndex == 0)
    {
        fByteCount--;
        fBitIndex = 8;
        fByteIndex = 0;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here are the full .cpp files if you need to understand what is happening...
IFStream12Bits.cpp

```
#include "IFStream12Bits.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


//default constructor
IFStream12Bits::IFStream12Bits()
{
    init();
}

//takes aFIleName
IFStream12Bits::IFStream12Bits(const char* aFileName)
{
    init();
    open(aFileName);
}

//deconstructor
IFStream12Bits::~IFStream12Bits()
{
    close();
}

//initialize the integer member variables with sensible values
//:fBuffer(), fByteCount(0), fByteIndex(0), fBitIndex(8)
//fBitIndex(highToLow)
void IFStream12Bits::init()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        fBuffer[i] = 0;
    }

    fByteCount = 0;
    fByteIndex = 0;
    fBitIndex = 8;
}

//fills input buffer fBuffer with the next 32 bytes and sets fByteCount to number of bytes read
void IFStream12Bits::reload()
{
    //fills fBuffer with 32 bytes
    fIStream.read((char*)fBuffer, 32);
    //fIStream.read((char*)fBuffer, fByteIndex + (fBitIndex % 8 ? 1 : 0));
    //sets fByteCount to number of bytes read
    fByteCount = fIStream.gcount();
}

//implements mapping process. returns 0 or 1 depending on value of fBuffer[fByteIndex] & (1 << (fBitIndex - 1))
//see how it works with experiments
//at start check if (fByteCount == 0){reload();} then use reload() called as buffer does not contain any data before calling reload
//next fetch the bit store and then advance fByteIndex and fBitIndex 
//if fBitIndex(highest to lowest) reaches 0 you need to switch to the next byte in the buffer. and also decrment fByteCount
//then finally return result
int IFStream12Bits::readBit()
{
    if (fByteCount == 0){ reload(); }

    //int bit = fBuffer[fByteIndex] & (1 << (fBitIndex - 1));

    int bit = fBuffer[fByteIndex] & (1 << (fBitIndex - 1));
    int result = 0;

    cout << "bit: " << bit << endl;

    if (bit == 0)
    {
        result = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        result = 1;
    }

    //additional logic required?
    fByteIndex++;
    fBitIndex--;


    //switch to next byte in the buffer
    if (fBitIndex == 0)
    {
        fByteCount--;
        fBitIndex = 8;
        fByteIndex = 0;
    }

    return result;
}

void IFStream12Bits::open(const char* aFileName)
{
    fIStream.open(aFileName, std::fstream::binary);
}

void IFStream12Bits::close()
{
    fIStream.close();
}

bool IFStream12Bits::fail()
{
    return fIStream.fail();
}

//true if no bytes left in input stream (fByteCount == 0)(should be zero if never read anythign from fIStream)
bool IFStream12Bits::eof()
{
    return fByteCount == 0;
}

//read 12Bit codes from the bit input stream implements the read12Bits algorithm as shown in the tutorial
//basic readBit
//read12Bits(): 12Bit =
//declare Result : 12Bit = 0;
//for i = 1 to 12
//do
//declare lBit : Bit = get bit from input
//if(lBit == 1)
//then Result = (1 << (i-1)) + Result; //set bit at index i
//od
//return result
// multiply values by 2 to shift left???????????
IFStream12Bits& IFStream12Bits::operator>>(int& a12BitValue)
{
    //int Result = a12BitValue;
    //a12BitValue = ((a12BitValue & 0x0fff) << 1);
    a12BitValue = a12BitValue & 0x0fff;


    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        int bit = readBit();
        if (bit == 1)
        {
            a12BitValue = (1 << (i - 1)) + a12BitValue; //set bit at index i
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

OFStream12Bits.cpp

```
#include "OFStream12Bits.h"

OFStream12Bits::OFStream12Bits()
{
    init();
}

OFStream12Bits::OFStream12Bits(const char* aFileName)
{
    init();
    open(aFileName);
}

OFStream12Bits::~OFStream12Bits()
{
    close();
}

void OFStream12Bits::init()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        fBuffer[i] = 0;
    }

    fByteIndex = 0;
    fBitIndex = 8;
}

void OFStream12Bits::writeBit0()
{
    fBitIndex--;
    finishWriteBit();
}

void OFStream12Bits::writeBit1()
{
    fBuffer[fByteIndex] += 1 << (fBitIndex - 1);
    fBitIndex--;
    finishWriteBit();
}

void OFStream12Bits::finishWriteBit()
{
    if (fBitIndex == 0)
    {
        if (fByteIndex == 31)
        {
            fByteIndex++;
            //write full buffer to stream
            flush();
        }
        else
        {
            fByteIndex++;
            fBitIndex = 8;
        }
    }
}

void OFStream12Bits::open(const char* aFileName)
{
    fOStream.open(aFileName, std::ofstream::binary);
}

bool OFStream12Bits::fail()
{
    return fOStream.fail();
}

void OFStream12Bits::close()
{
    flush();
    fOStream.close();
}

void OFStream12Bits::flush()
{
    //                                     do we need to add last byte?
    fOStream.write((char*)fBuffer, fByteIndex + (fBitIndex % 8 ? 1 : 0));
    init();
}

OFStream12Bits& OFStream12Bits::operator<<(int a12BitValue)
{
    a12BitValue = a12BitValue & 0x0fff; // mask 12 lower bits

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) //write 12 bits
    {
        if (a12BitValue & 0x01) // the current lowest bit is set
        {
            writeBit1();
        }
        else
        {
            writeBit0();
        }
        a12BitValue >>= 1; // code = code / 2 --shifting value accross
    }

    return *this;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "OFStream12Bits.h"
#include "IFStream12Bits.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void write4096()
{
    cout << "Write 4096 codes" << endl;

    OFStream12Bits lWriter("sample.lzw");

    if (lWriter.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Error: unable to open output file" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 4096; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        lWriter << i;
    }
}

void read4096()
{
    cout << "Read 4096 codes" << endl;

    IFStream12Bits lInput("sample.lzw");

    if (lInput.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Error: unable to open input file!" << endl;
        exit(2);
    }

    for (int i = 4095; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        int l12BitValue; 

        lInput >> l12BitValue;

        if (l12BitValue != i)
        {
            cerr << "Error: Code mismatch: " << l12BitValue << " != " << i << endl;
            exit(3);
        }
    }

    if (!lInput.eof())
    {
        cerr << "Error: Input stream not exhausted" << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    write4096();
    read4096();
    cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would state what input you're giving it, what output you're receiving and what output you're expecting.

Comment: The input should be created as sample.lzw by the OFStream12Bits.cpp/main.cpp included  and the output should be reading the sample.lzw back from the write functions(OFStream12Bits.cpp/main.cpp).

Comment: okay let me put this another way. Given the comment you've just supplied, how do you (or I or anyone else, for that matter) know the code isn't functioning as expected? I was actually asking "what data" is going in, what is coming out and what are you expecting - **not how or where do you get it from**. The code is incomplete (i.e can't be compiled) and seems to include much which doesn't really help at all, merely getting in the way by virtue of its length. These oversights on your part make it harder for readers of SO to help you, regardless of how much they'd like to. ;)

Comment: What enhzflep said. It would make it easier to help you if you provided a [mcve]. And you might like to ask your professor if it's ok to get help on SO with this assignment...

Answer (score 1):

Your input code is starting with the previous value.  You should start with 0, because you're not clearing bits that aren't set.

```
IFStream12Bits& IFStream12Bits::operator>>(int& a12BitValue)
{
    a12BitValue = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        int bit = readBit();
        if (bit == 1)
        {
            a12BitValue = (1 << (i - 1)) + a12BitValue; //set bit at index i
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Also, `+` will work here, but it's clearer to use bitwise operations when dealing with bits.  Additionally, I think your shift is off.  I would write the set bit line like this:

```
a12BitValue |= 1 << i;
```

If you think about it, when `i` is 0, you want to set the first bit (which is `1` or `1 << 0`.)  When `i` is 1, you want the next bit, and so on.  So you should not need to subtract one.

I'm not sure that's the only problem, but you might try testing each class independently with unit tests.  For example, start with a raw byte buffer, like `{0x89, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF, 0x01}`, and then read three sets of 12 bits off.  Verify they are correct.  Then create an empty buffer, and write specific bits to it, and check that the bytes are correct.

By testing the algorithms independently, and with very strict input/output, you'll find it much easier to determine the flaw.